# Get element's index in mybatis foreach tag ?

Tags: mybatis

I am trying to iterate through arraylist in mybatis and want to pass the position of the element to (like a[i], then i want the value of i for each element) is there a way to do that in mybatis ?

Comment: Doesn't declaring the `index="index"` variable like described in http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#foreach work?

Comment: When we declare index = "index" it stores the size-1 value in the index but not the index of current item, please let me know if there is any other way to achieve that.

Comment: Perhaps you need to update to a newer version, works for me (see answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following query to test this...

```
<select id="test" resultType="Long" parameterType="something.Testy">       
   <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list" open="" separator=" UNION " close="">
         SELECT #{index} FROM DUAL
    </foreach>        
</select>
```

with `something.Testy` being a simple Object:

```
public class Testy {

    public List<Integer> getList() {
        return Arrays.asList( 4, 5, 6 );
    }

}
```

The result of this is a list `[ 0, 1, 2 ]`, so the `#{index}` get's correctly determined with the current MyBatis release (3.3.0). The query that MyBatis creates looks like this...

```
SELECT ? FROM DUAL UNION SELECT ? FROM DUAL UNION SELECT ? FROM DUAL 
Parameters: 0(Integer), 1(Integer), 2(Integer)
```

Perhaps you need to update your MyBatis version? Might be a bug in an older one...

Comment: Yup, by updating the myBatis version it got resolved, thanks a lot :)